# Subtracting fix date from whole panda data frame - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, subtraction

I have data

```
    customer_id purchase_amount date_of_purchase
0   760       25.0  06-11-2009
1   860      50.0   09-28-2012
2   1200    100.0   10-25-2005
3   1420    50.0    09-07-2009
4   1940    70.0    01-25-2013
5   1960    40.0    10-29-2013
6   2620    30.0    09-03-2006
7   3050    50.0    12-04-2007
8   3120    150.0   08-11-2006
9   3260    45.0    10-20-2010
10  3510    35.0    04-05-2013
11  3970    30.0    07-06-2007
12  4000    20.0    11-25-2005
13  4180    20.0    09-22-2010
14  4390    30.0    04-15-2011
15  4750    60.0    02-12-2013
16  4840    30.0    10-14-2005
17  4910    15.0    12-13-2006
18  4950    50.0    05-19-2010
19  4970    30.0    01-12-2006
20  5250    50.0    12-20-2005
```

Now I want to subtract `01-01-2016` from each row of `date_of_purchase`

I tried the following so I should have a new column `days_since` with a number of days.

```
NOW = pd.to_datetime('01/01/2016').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
gb = customer_purchases_df.groupby('customer_id')
df2 = gb.agg({'date_of_purchase': lambda x: (NOW - x.max()).days})
```

any suggestion. how I can achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you grouping and not simply subtracting the datetime from the last column?

Comment: But there is no `01-01-2016` date in your data?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('01/01/2016')` is a `Timestamp` object.  `pd.to_datetime('01/01/2016').strftime('%m-%d-%Y')` is a string.  If your `date_of_purchase` column is indeed a datetime column then you are trying to subtract a string from a date.  Then there is the question of why you are using `groupby`.  As @timgeb said, you don't need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_purchase']).rsub(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')).dt.days

0     2395
1     1190
2     3720
3     2307
4     1071
5      794
6     3407
7     2950
8     3430
9     1899
10    1001
11    3101
12    3689
13    1927
14    1722
15    1053
16    3731
17    3306
18    2053
19    3641
20    3664
Name: date_of_purchase, dtype: int64
```

Comment: You can also try `rsub` which assumes the calling pandas object is the operand on the right side of the subtraction: `pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_purchase']).rsub(pd.to_datetime('2016-01-01')).dt.days`

Comment: Good suggestion.

Comment: @piRSquared Congrats on 200K!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the `'date_of_purchase'` column already has the datetime dtype.

```
>>> df
   customer_id  purchase_amount date_of_purchase
0          760             25.0       2009-06-11
1          860             50.0       2012-09-28
2         1200            100.0       2005-10-25
>>> df['days_since'] = df['date_of_purchase'].sub(pd.to_datetime('01/01/2016')).dt.days.abs()
>>> df 
   customer_id  purchase_amount date_of_purchase  days_since
0          760             25.0       2009-06-11        2395
1          860             50.0       2012-09-28        1190
2         1200            100.0       2005-10-25        3720
```